# TypeORM: How to run SELECT... FOR UPDATE inside queryRunner?

Tags: typeorm

How can I run `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` inside `queryRunner`  ?
I see the TypeORM doc that queryRunner can only access `manager`, how I can access `Repository` to lock record. For example `queryRunner.getRepository(User).setLock("pessimistic_write").....`

```
      console.log("----------------- START TRANSACTION -----------------");

      const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();
      // establish real database connection using our new query runner
      await queryRunner.connect();

      await queryRunner.startTransaction();

      try {
        // `SELECT....FOR UPDATE`
        // Want to .setLock("pessimistic_write")


        // commit transaction now:
        await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
      } catch (err) {
        // since we have errors lets rollback changes we made
        await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      } finally {
        // you need to release query runner which is manually created:
        await queryRunner.release();
      }

      console.log("----------------- FINISH TRANSACTION -----------------");
```

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yupp, actually we can access `Repository` from `manager`, problem solved

```js
        users = await queryRunner.manager
          .getRepository(User)
          .createQueryBuilder("user")
          .useTransaction(true)
          .setLock("pessimistic_write")
          .where("user.status = :status", { status: status })
          .getMany();
```

Comment: I start a transaction with a query runner. Would this code wrap the query into another transaction or the one I already have?